# Is “even through” typo?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

When I studied EIKEN Grade1 which is one of the English examination of Japan, I saw a sentence below.

> A kitchen knife that could slash even **through** bone was advertised
>   on television.

I think this sentence contains typo, not “even through” but “even though”.
Is it OK my assumption?

Comment: Not a typo...it means "including" bone. Look up " through". Possibly it might be better re-ordered.

Comment: Dear Cascabel, thank you for your comment. I understand it is not a typo.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't relate to "even though".

For clarity, you could read the sentence as "could even slash through".

Comment: Dear Matt S, thank you for your comment. Your alternative sentence, “could even slash through” are understandable for me.